# how to setting rewrite rule, codeigniter .htaccess in mac osx

Tags: macos, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, nginx

i want to setting my nginx.conf and .htacccess(codeigniter) i was tried setting rewrite in my nginx.conf, but not success,

this is my nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  4;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
server_tokens off;

include mime.types;
default_type text/plain;

log_format gzip '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
                '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
                '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

access_log /usr/local/logs/nginx/access.log gzip buffer=32k;
error_log /usr/local/logs/nginx/error.log notice;

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;
root /usr/local/var/www;
index  index.php index.html;

location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
}

include fastcgi_params;
}

include /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/*;
include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

for this case, my .htaccess file is empty,
anyone help me...

thx

Comment: nginx doesn't support htaccess for what I know you need to put the rewrite rules inside the conf of nginx & it has it's own syntax.

Comment: @ahmad: may you give me an example nginx.conf for rewrite rules?

Comment: I have no idea how it works, but here's a website which would convert htaccess rules to nginx rules: http://www.anilcetin.com

Comment: thx ahmad, finally my problem is solved, nginx codeigniter cannot setting .htaccess but only setting on nginx.conf